# How to pass values of controls from view to controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my model. I'm using strongly typed model. But when I tried to use dropdown value then it is problem for me as:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Controller for Add routine(Create Record)

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.MovieType = new SelectList(new[] {"Comedy","Romantic","Action","Thriller" });
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         db.Movies.Add(movie);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

Here is my specific portion of view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genre)
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("MyItems",(SelectList) ViewBag.MovieType)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
</div>
```

Although `dropdown` is working fine. The issue is that I'm using 
  `@Html.Editorfor` for other model fields and I'm receiving the `model` values but for this `Genre` for movieType I'm getting `null` value.

I tried `Viewbag` with `@Html.Editorfor` but I could not find overload. Can anyone let me know how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

You binding the dropdown list to a property named `MyItems` which does not exist.  Change it to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, (SelectList)ViewBag.MovieType)
```

Note also that you must reassign the value of `ViewBag.MovieType` in the POST method if you return the view (i.e. when `ModelState` if invalid)

```
public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Movies.Add(movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.MovieType = new SelectList(new[] {"Comedy","Romantic","Action","Thriller" }); // add this
    return View(movie);
}
```